# Is it insecure to let users know which framework I am using?

Tags: mobile

Suppose I use a framework X to build a mobile game, and the website of X allows me to submit the name of app that uses X to build. But I suspect if I should submit my app name because it would let users know my app is using X. Is letting users to know which framework I am using a security issue?

Comment: Not really. It's probably pretty easy to figure out if someone was determined/cared enough. Unless of course that framework has a known vuln. Then you may not want to advertise...

Comment: Always good to follow the principal of least privilege. Users don't need to know this information, so don't give it to them. Of course as has been mentioned, it may be possible to find out anyway. However the rule still applies. Don't give out any information you don't need to. X can do their own self-promotion without listing apps directly.

Comment: @user1751825: knowledge of the framework is not a privilege which means that the principal of least privilege does not apply here.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Technically true. The same basic concept applies though. Users do not need to know anything about the technical implementation of the app in order to use it, therefore this information should not be provided to them. I guess what I mean is the "need-to-know" principal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Security through obscurity is not sufficient**, but can be used aggregated to other security mechanisms and practices. Always remember that system security should not depend only on the secrecy of the implementation or its components.

You can know the framework code very well, but you can't suppose it's completely safe. Hiding it does not change that, but certainly can add an extra safety, which doesn't mean you shouldn't care about how code is implemented because it's hidden.

Avoid unused libraries, keep the code clean and lean, validate input data and encode output data, authenticate credentials, control access, treat log error messages, etc. There are a lot of good practices that should be used, because **only hiding your code is not enough.**

Answer (score 0):

I would describe it as defense in depth measure.  Not something to rely on, but if you can get away with it, might be useful.  If an attacker can identify any part of the stack they could start looking for known weaknesses in it, and possibly exploit it from there.

Doing this simply adds more time and effort on the part of the attacker to find a vulnerability, if you can make it prohibitive enough then a speculative attacker may get bored and look elsewhere.

So there is small benefit, but I wouldn`t bet the ranch on it alone.

Answer (score 0):

First, it is always good **to disclose as little information as possible** to any potential attacker. You should find answers to the following points in order to answer your question:

1. What security record does your framework have? Are there many known flaws from the past? Are the developers of that framework known for favor features over security?
2. What are the benefits of submitting your app on their website? Is that really important to you?
3. Did you closely follow recommendations for writing secure software? In other words: How much effort did you spent at making your own code safe? Is it likely that one of the classical attack vectors will work in your own code regardless of any framework?

The security of your app mainly depends on 1 and 3 so that is what you should look at first, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I was taught to reduce the given Information to the users to a minimum.
Regardless of that, a dedicated attacker will find what system you're using in no time.

In both cases the attacker would search for common exploits, but it would make it a little bit harder, if you're not telling, what youre using. 
Maybe this would also scare away script kiddies.

Comment: Isn't that just security by obscurity?

Comment: @Alpha3031 Indeed